# Margin bottom doesn't want to work in Opera and Safari

Tags: html, css, safari, margin, opera

i'm new in web design ,i have been doing this code html/css which is about  margins in css it really looks easy but  the margin-bottom doesnt work in all the browsers. I tested it in Chrome,Internet explorer 11,Firefox and it works but it doesnt work in Opera and Safari. i don't know if i make a mistake because i'm noob or is because of the browser.

This is my code HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <title>CALCULADORA DE CREDITOS - CECyT No. 1 "GONZALO VAZQUEZ VELA" DEL IPN</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="prueba.css">
</head>

<body>
   <div id="wrapper">
      Hellow ,i'm a DIV!
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is my CSS 'prueba.css':

```
*{margin:0;
padding:0;}


html,body{height:100%;}


body{margin:4%;}

#wrapper{
margin:0 auto 0 auto;
background-color:gray;
width:60%;
height:100%;
}
```

Comment: 1. On what element is the margin not working? 2. I don't see a specific margin-bottom in your code.

Comment: Exactly in the margin bottom of the body.

Comment: You don't need to put `html,body{height:100%}`. That is most likely what is causing your issue because your body is trying to be full width and height + 4% (108%). JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yFvLT/

Comment: you're right but i have the same problem in Opera and Safari.any sugestion

Comment: If your content is natively greater than the size of the window, you could just remove the `html,body{height:100%}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove these parts:

```
html,body{height:100%;}
body{margin:4%;}
```

when making elements specific sizes, only use percentages when you're using "position: fixed" on the selected element.

set the margin in the element itself instead, also setting the element in percentages only works when you have a "position: fixed" on your element.

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/457Zu/3/)